# From XML to XML within XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following XML

```
<ROOT>
  <COUNTRY Name="Ukraine">
    <CITY>
        <POPULATION>1427000</POPULATION> 
        <NAME>Kharkov</NAME>
        <SQUARE>310 km2</SQUARE>
    </CITY>
    <CITY>
      <POPULATION>2758000</POPULATION>
      <NAME>Kiev</NAME>
      <SQUARE>839 km2</SQUARE>
    </CITY>
  </COUNTRY>
  <COUNTRY Name="England">
    <CITY>
      <POPULATION>7000000</POPULATION>
      <NAME>London</NAME>
      <SQUARE>1579 km2</SQUARE>
    </CITY>
  </COUNTRY>
</ROOT>
```

I need to use XSLT and get such result

```
<ROOT>
  <CITY Name="...", Population="...", Square="...", Country="..." />
</ROOT>
```

I already write some part of this XSLT, but it works correctly only for one COUNTRY

```
  <xsl:template match="COUNTRY">
    <ROOT>
      <CITY>
          <xsl:attribute name="Name">
            <xsl:value-of select="CITY/NAME"/>, Population:<xsl:value-of select="CITY/POPULATION"/>, Square:<xsl:value-of select="CITY/SQUARE"/>, Country:<xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </CITY>
      </ROOT>
  </xsl:template>
```

And I have no idea how should it work for a few countries and cities. I'm new in XSLT, so I need your help.

Comment: You might want to match on `CITY`, and look for the country name in the city's parent node. Also, commas are not part of a valid XML tag.

Comment: Thank you! But how can I see country name in city's parent node if I'll match on CITY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through each CITY.  The following XSLT should do the job:

```
<xsl:template match="/ROOT">
<ROOT>
  <xsl:for-each select="COUNTRY/CITY">
  <CITY>
    <xsl:attribute name="Name"><xsl:value-of select="NAME"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="Population"><xsl:value-of select="POPULATION"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="Square"><xsl:value-of select="SQUARE"/></xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="Country"><xsl:value-of select="../@Name"/></xsl:attribute>
  </CITY>
  </xsl:for-each>
</ROOT>
</xsl:template>
```

Notice the usage of `../@Name`, which indicates the `Name` attribute of the parent element (COUNTRY).

Example result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
  <CITY Name="Kharkov" Population="1427000" Square="310 km2" Country="Ukraine"/>
  <CITY Name="Kiev" Population="2758000" Square="839 km2" Country="Ukraine"/>
  <CITY Name="London" Population="7000000" Square="1579 km2" Country="England"/>
</ROOT>
```

Comment: That's it! And about parent element, I should have guessed because it's the same thing like a path to a file in C#